# BigQuery ML forecast using ARIMA_PLUS (mostly) ignores the holiday effect

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, arima

I'm trying to forecast daily sales for a business using the past 5 years of daily sales history. This business has very clear holiday sales patterns, including zero sales on Easter/Thanksgiving/Christmas and unusually high sales on Valentine's Day, Mother's Day, etc.

Only two dates in the resulting model that have a non-zero holiday effect: December 23 and President's Day. I cannot figure out why.

I'm using the ARIMA_PLUS model type in BigQuery ML, with the `holiday_region` set to 'US'. The data is simply `date` and `sales`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `model_name`
OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE='ARIMA_PLUS',
    time_series_timestamp_col='date',
    time_series_data_col='sales',
    data_frequency='DAILY',
    holiday_region='US') AS
( SELECT date, sales FROM `table_name`);
```

An example of an obvious forecasting error is that April 9, 2023 (Easter) is forecasted as a normal sales day (instead of zero), and April 17, 2023 is forecasted to be zero. The business was closed on April 17, 2022 due to Easter, so the model is clearly ignoring the Easter holiday and providing an inaccurate forecast as a result.

I used the `EXPLAIN_FORECAST` function to see if any days had a holiday effect, which is where I found it was just December 23 and President's Day. There were adjustments for those two days across each of the five years of history. The `holiday_effect` field was zero for the rest of the dates.

```
SELECT * FROM ML.EXPLAIN_FORECAST(MODEL `model_name`, STRUCT(14 AS horizon, 0.8 AS confidence_level));
```

Any idea why the model ignores all holidays except these two? Is this a defect in BigQuery ML, or is there something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dip on `2023-04-17` might be a result of `YEARLY` seasonality effect.

In your model creation setting, `SEASONALITY` is default to `AUTO`. Given that your data frequency is `DAILY` and time series length is longer than `2 years`, it will automatically infer the `SEASONALITY` as `WEEKLY` and `YEARLY`. It is indeed the `YEARLY` seasonality that captures the dip from `2022` this time.

To workaround that, you can set `SEASONALITY = ['WEEKLY']` in `OPTIONS` clause explicitly to avoid modeling with `YEARLY` seasonality.